# Android Table Layout Alignment

Tags: android, alignment, android-tablelayout

I am using Table Layout to display data as shown below.
[image]

**What i want to do ?**

I want the Text in the second column to be aligned to the left and the text should wrap and be displayed in the next line and over flow as you see in the image.

**Code:**

```
    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="ss"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_category"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="230 kms"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="ss"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_category"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Hill Station, Wild Life"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="ss"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_category"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Summer 23-40°C, Winter 10-32°C"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="ss"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_category"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Tippus Drop, Tippus Summer Residence, Brahmashram, Cycling, Paragliding"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

What it should look like

[image]

Comment: Try to textview padding?

Comment: @Dinesh yeah i tried that. doesnt really help

Comment: you mean you want 230km at left side

Comment: can you explain the requirement to mean in detail please.

Comment: @Nick yeah i want the Second Column to be left aligned next to the icon. And the text to wrap to next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to wrap each `TableRow` content with a `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="ss"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="230 kms"
                    android:textSize="16sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="ss"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Hill Station, Wild Life"
                    android:textSize="16sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="ss"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Summer 23-40°C, Winter 10-32°C"
                    android:textSize="16sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:contentDescription="ss"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Tippus Drop, Tippus Summer Residence, Brahmashram, Cycling, Paragliding"
                    android:textSize="16sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image: layout]

Hope I correctly understood your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to make the Last set of rows. to start at the center and then flow downwards ? have updated my answer to show what i want to achieve

Comment: If you add paddingTop to the TextView you can achieve this. I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way of doing this though.

Answer (score 2):

Since a [`TableRow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) is pretty much a horizontally oriented `LinearLayout`, simply use the principles of weights to make the `TextView` fill up all the space after the `ImageView`. It means you'd have to change the rows to somewhat like this:

```
    <!-- no need to set width/height as those are implicitly enforced -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/place_category_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="ss"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_category" />

        <!-- width of '0' and weight of '1' will make this view fill up all remaining space -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="230 kms"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </TableRow>
```

I've also removed/changed some superfluous attributes. Do mind that I just typed this directly in the browser - there may be the odd typo or tweak required.

Comment: you have provided android:layout_width="0dp" why is it ZERO ?

Comment: That's common practice when dealing with weights and `LinearLayout`s, as it speeds up the measurement/layout process. In this scenario you don't care about the initial width, but rather how the remaining space is distributed amongst the child views. For this specific case it'll work fine with e.g. `wrap_content` too; it's just slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

My guess - change the layout_width and get rid of the gravity:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            ...
            >
        </TextView>
```