# How to align text one below the other in android?

Tags: android, alignment, textview

I'm working on android app. Here I have 2 `TextView` which I need to align one below the other.`(i.e "Artist Name" should be exact below the "Title of song" )`

Could anyone help me in aligning the `TextView` one below the other. 
Thanks in advance.

**Below is my code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:
  android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:padding="5dip" >

  <TableLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

  <!--  Left side Thumbnail image -->
  <TableRow android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="3dip"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:src="@drawable/doc"/>



 <!-- Title Of Song-->
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/title"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:text="love you the"
 android:textColor="#040404"
 android:typeface="sans"
 android:textSize="15dip"
 android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Artist Name -->
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/artist"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/title"
  android:textColor="#343434"
  android:textSize="10sp"
  android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
  android:text="Mary" />

  <!-- Rightend Duration -->
  <TextView
 android:id="@+id/duration"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
 android:gravity="right"
 android:text="7:45"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
 android:textSize="10dip"
 android:textColor="#10bcc9"
 android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/arrows"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The trick here is that android:gravity is the proper property, use it.

Comment: This is the best example for your program check the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000755/android-table-layout-alignment

Comment: try to use LinearLayout or use the property  `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"`

Comment: @ Jay , it didnt work :(

Comment: @ Ramki Anba , already used , android:layout_below="@+id/title"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) to place your Item's to related to other's.

androidHacker is right, you can place one text view to below of other like this:

**`android:layout_below="@+id/your_another_text_view"`**

Similar layout is [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) in this tutorial for that you are looking here.

Comment: still the text is same (i.e not aligned below "the title of song)

Comment: just remove this line   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" > from haresh answer@user3607124

Comment: @ Robi Kumar Tomar , after removing android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" > the whole content is getting aligned to left

Comment: Did you read the last link that i have attached here, it show the same view as u wants. Just use this  http://pastebin.com/4xy2KEWu  @user3607124

Comment: @ Robi Kumar Tomar, sure will go through that and let you know
Thank you

Comment: @user3607124  Glad it help you, just say thanks by ticking up and accepting it. so that it can help to other.

Comment: @ Robi Kumar Tomar , I have another doubt , if i want to use TableLayout, (i.e if i want same similar rows many) . How should i do it ?

Comment: Just use listview and inflate a view to listview show that you can fill the data to each row of your listview. use this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 2):

try like this..

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/your_another_text_view"
```

**UPDATE**

You just need to make use of relative layout specifically for that textView.. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <!--  Left side Thumbnail image -->
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/list_image"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
                    android:text="love you the"
                    android:textColor="#040404"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <!-- Artist Name -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/artist"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/title"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
                    android:textColor="#343434"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:text="Mary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/duration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="7:45"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/arrow_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/duration"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @ Haresh , text is getting align but whole content is getting align at the center :(

Comment: try to remove this properties android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  from TableLayout.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/title"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:text="love you the"
 android:textColor="#040404"
 android:typeface="sans"
 android:textSize="15dip"
 android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Artist Name -->
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/artist"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/title"
  android:textColor="#343434"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"// This line is new
  android:textSize="10sp"
  android:layout_marginTop="1dip"

  android:text="Mary" />
```

Comment: @ Wasim Ahmed , didnt help :(

Comment: you have accepted an answer..so i think you dont need furthure any answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use LinearLayout or use the property  `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"`